# Multiplying convergent sequence by divergent sequences of natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{x_k\}$ be a sequence converging to the limit $a \ne 0$ and let $\{n_k\} \subset \mathbb{N} $ be a divergent sequence of natural numbers.
I want to show that the sequence $\{x_k n_k\}$ is divergent.
It seemed easy but I could not prove it.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hint: $1/x_k$ is convergent and $n_k = (x_k n_k) \cdot (1/x_k)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael following your hint: assume by contradiction that $\{x_kn_k\}$ converges to $b$ , then from limits arithmetic we get $\{(x_k n_k)⋅(1/x_k)\} \rightarrow b/a$ but $(x_k n_k)⋅(1/x_k) = n_k$ - contradiction

Comment: I wonder how it can be proved more directly using the limit definition.

Answer (score 0):

Proof for the case that $n_k$ is bounded:

$n_k$ is divergent and natural, so for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there are $p>q>N$ s.t $|n_p-n_q| \ge 1$

$n_k$ is bounded so let $M \ge 1$ be an upper bound

Let $\epsilon = \frac{|a|}{4M}$
Since $x_n \rightarrow a$, there is a $K$ s.t $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$ for all $n>K$. Also there are $p,q>K$ s.t. $|n_p-n_q| \ge 1$, This implies:

$$|n_px_p-n_qx_q|>|a(n_p-n_q)|-\epsilon(n_p+n_q)> |a| - 2M\epsilon = |a| - \frac{|a|}{2M} $$

And therefore $\{x_kn_k\}$ is divergent.